# How to delete keyboard shortcut ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

I set <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> combination key to change language, but now I want to delete it due to conflict with others.

I tried doing the reset from settings->Devices->Keyboard but it still  remains.

Can someone help?

Comment: I don't remember how i done that,i just want to delete this combination

Comment: Technically, that's an `xkb option`, not a shortcut. I don't remember where they can be configured, but look for something like "additional options" in the keyboard configuration.